# Grails Controller: Render String as JSON Response

Tags: json, grails, controller

I have a simple autocomplete text-input field on my GSP that gets its values (a list of countries) from a controller via AJAX request. All works fine if the controller looks like this:

```
def getAllCountries() {
  def countries = [[name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'],[name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'],[...
  render countries as JSON
}
```

However, If would like to pass the countries within a string that already contains the countries in a json formatted way, so I can use different representations of the string for Internationalisaion, like this:

```
def countries = "[{'name':'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},{'name':'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'},{'name':'Albania', code: 'AL'},{..."
```

However, now I receive a casting exception when I call render countries as JSON.

Is there any way I can pass the String directly to the view?

Thank you very much in adavance.

Answer (score 13):

If you already have the response in JSON format, you could render it directly.

```
response.setContentType("application/json")
render '[{"name":"Afghanistan","code":"AF"},{"name":"Aland Islands","code":"AX"},{"name":"Albania","code":"AL"}]'
```

Answer (score 3):

The render method accepts text as parameter as well:

```
render contentType: "text/json", text: '[{"name":"Afghanistan" ...}]'
```

Comment: shouldn't we use "application/json" instead of "text/json"?

Comment: Yes, application/json is the official standard, but most tools understand text/json too because of historical reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Rendering `[[name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF']] as JSON` will result as `[{"name":"Afghanistan","code":"AF"}]`, and it doesn't make sense to try convert already json formatted String to JSON.
If you have `"[{'name':'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'}]"`, just use it without converting to Json.